# php variable inside javascript code

Tags: javascript

I placed a javascript inside a .php file

```
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {         
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#particles').particleground({
                dotColor: '<?=json_encode($dotcolor)?>',
                lineColor: '#5cb9bd',                   
              });
            });
        }
     );
    </script>";
```

and tried to use `<?=json_encode($dotcolor)?>` to echo a variable. But it isn't working.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php $script = "<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {         
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#particles').particleground({
                dotColor: " . json_encode($dotcolor) . ",
                lineColor: '#5cb9bd',                   
              });
            });
        }
     );
    </script>";
    ?>
```

**Note:**
Its a better practice to enqueue Javascripts with `wp_enqueue_script()` and include dynamic strings via `wp_localize_script()`.

**Docs:**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script